# Can I track the progress when downloading a response from SOLR?

Tags: http, solr

One question about SOLR. I have to send a request to get thousands of geolocations. The response follos the json format. My question is if I can track the download progress. I guess that's normal in any http request but not sure. I guess I receive the content-size header at the beginning, or maybe I have to use HEAD. No idea. Any advice?
Thanks for help.

Comment: I find some solutions to that problem, by they work based on javascript code. Does it suitable for you?

Comment: I have to do the request under iOS, so I will use AFNetworking or RestKit. In the worst case, low level HTTP methods from Apple. What was your problem and how did you solve it? Thanks for the info.

Comment: I simple solution might be to use pagination with Solr. Say you want a progress bar with 10 stages.

First check the number of results found. Then return your results in 10 separate chunks using the pagination feature of Solr. (of course you have to handle these events on the UI side)

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results

Comment: So, I understand is not possible using HTTP, isn't it?